# GITLAB-CI pipeline cant login into insecure regestry

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

my pipeline cant login into my private registry that doesnt have ssl, so when the pipeline does docker login it tries to connect with https.

added the command option as seen in other answers on stackoverflow

```
services:   
   - name: docker:dind     
   command: ["--insecure-registry=$REGISTRY_URL"]
```

added this thing on /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myregistry:5000"]
}
```

```
stages:
    - build
    - test
    - build_container
    - deploy


variables:
    REGISTRY_URL: myregistry:5000
    CONTAINER_TAG: latest
    REGISTRY_PROJECT: hello-world
    TEST_TAG: teste


services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=$REGISTRY_URL"]

before_script:
   - uname -a

build:
  stage: build
  image: gcc
  script:
    - make -f Makefile
  artifacts:
    paths:
        - i386/hello-world/
    expire_in: 1 week


deploy:                 <---- PROBLEM STARTS HERE
   stage: deploy
   image: docker:latest
   environment:
    name: deploy
   script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin $REGISTRY_URL
    - docker pull $REGISTRY_URL/$REGISTRY_PROJECT:$CONTAINER_TAG
    - docker tag $REGISTRY_URL/$REGISTRY_PROJECT:$TEST_TAG
    - docker push REGISTRY_URL/$REGISTRY_PROJECT:$TEST_TAG
```

i'm getting this error message:

```
time="2019-05-07T14:08:47Z" level=info msg="Error logging in to v2 endpoint, trying next endpoint: Get https://myregistry:5000/v2/: dial tcp: lookup myregistry on 193.XX.XX.XX:53: no such host"
```

if i remove $REGISTRY_URL from:

```
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin $REGISTRY_URL
```

then i can login, but i then i cant do a pull because the docker image doesnt reach the registry? i think

Comment: I have same problem. How do you solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the command insecure registry, you have to define the variable DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR with an empty string: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''